# Sci-fi/Fantasy book about bear postman on a planet of bears

Tags: story-identification, books

Trying to find a book I remember reading probably in the early 80s.  The protagonist is an anthropomorphic bear on a planet of bears.  He’s a postman or a mailman, which is a prestigious job.

Comment: Hi there. That's some info already, but please take a look at [thse guidelines][https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories to [edit] in. For instance, you say it's sci-fi/fantasy - what other aspects of sci-fi or fantasy did that book have? Was it normal that the bears could talk, post mail etc? Or had they been uplifted or something?

Comment: Could it be [this children's book?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvWzj2TFqKM)

Comment: @JBH in which case it doesn't seem on-topic, same as [Mr Bear, Postman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efgLerz1Qj8)

Comment: @Jenayah, there's a point to be made there.  Not exactly scifi-y are they?

Comment: It doesn't really bear thinking about.

Comment: @JBH not sure what you mean? Both things we linked to are off-topic, from a quick glance at it, per the "anthropomorphic animals are SFF if they've been uplifted or aren't seen as normal etc" policy

Comment: @Jenayah Since when is a story set on another planet not sci-fi? Or are you thinking that the "planet of bears" mentioned in the question is our earth?

Comment: @user14111 IIRC, I did mean the books JBH and I linked (not the question). Was it specifically mentioned in the videos that they're on another planet? (Can't access YouTube right now...) Per my comment above I seemed to think that​ the off-topicness stemmed more from our "talking animals" policy

Comment: @Jenayah Sorry for my careless reading, I thought you were suggesting the question was off topic.

Answer (score 17):

This sounds like the 1st story in [*The Right to Arm Bears*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Right_to_Arm_Bears) by Gordon R. Dickson. It's an omnibus of 3 stories involving the bears-like aliens of the planet Dilbia.

The first story, "Spacial Delivery" is about a human (John Tardy/Half-Pint Posted) who is delivered to his destination by the "stalwart Dilbian postman Hill Bluffer".

The second story was also a novel "Spacepaw", and the third is a short story, "The Law-Twister Shorty" which before the omnibus appeared in various collections.

### Cover of the 1983 edition of the stand-alone novel [*Spacial Delivery*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3750)

[image: Cover of 1983 edition of Spacial Delivery]

Comment: Could you edit to explain why this sounds like the story the OP has described?

Comment: You're probably right (+1) but please include the title of the story and some of explanation of how it matches the OP's description, perhaps with a quotation or two from the story. The first story in that collection (Gordon Dickson's *Dilbia* series) is "The Man in the Mailbag", which is available at https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v17n04_1959-04/page/n160

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - is it policy here to suppress the location of a link? i try to avoid posting links that don't show the destination. ///// yes, i can add the why of it. give me a bit to read up. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey it's more about formatting​, plain links are kind of ugly... The link is still here, wrapping the story title, and anyone can preview it in their browser before going to the address

Comment: @Jenayah - it makes me uncomfy ... but this is y'alls playground, so i will do my best to abide by the local customs. [*grin*] thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Note that *The Right to Arm Bears" was first published in 2000, so if the OP read this in the early 1980s it was almost definitely as a stand-alone novel.